# Free cocompletion for non-small categories

Tags: logic, category-theory, soft-question

Why is $\mathcal C$ assumed to be small in [this proposition](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/free+cocompletion#proofs) (stating that $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathcal C^\mathrm{op}}$ is the free cocompletion of $\mathcal C$)?

In particular I don't understand the comment above the proposition:

> If $C$ is not small, then its free cocompletion still exists, but it is not the category of all presheaves on $C$. Rather, it is the category of small presheaves on $C$, i.e. presheaves that are small colimits of representables.

Why? I don't see what goes wrong in the proof when $C$ is not small.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer is mostly that several of the terms/theorems have an omitted "small" if you're being really pedantic.

For instance, $\mathbf{Set}$ is cocomplete, which means it has all *small* colimits. It doesn't necessarily have large colimits.

When $C$ is small, the co-Yoneda lemma leads to the conclusion that *every* presheaf in $\mathbf{Set}^{C^{op}}$ is a *small* colimit of representables. So, if you take the subcategory picked out by the Yoneda embedding, then add in all *small* colimits (the cocompletion), you will get all of $\mathbf{Set}^{C^{op}}$.

But, if $C$ is large, then even a co-Yoneda lemma for $C$ would only give you that every presheaf is a *large* colimit of representables, not necessarily a *small* colimit. So the free *small* cocompletion may not be *all* presheaves, just the *small* colimits of representables.

Comment: Thanks, that's enlightening, but strictly speaking it doesn't answer my question: which step in the proof that $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathcal C^\mathrm{op}}$ is the free cocompletion of $C$ fails for $C$ large? The uniqueness of $\widetilde F$ can be proven without knowing that every presheaf is a small colimit of representables (note that in the statement we talk about colimit preserving functors - these preserve *all* colimits).

Comment: You say that for $C$ large a preseheaf is only a *large* colimit of representables - but you don't explain what the issue with that is. Co-Yoneda is only used in the uniqueness part, and that part works for $C$ large just as for small categories.

Comment: "So the free small cocompletion may not be all presheaves, just the small colimits of representables." Thanks for repeating the statement I want an explanation for. My question is not to repeat that statement, but to explain *why*. :-)

Comment: By the way I'm having the proof in Mac Lane-Moerdijk *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic* on page 43 in mind.

Comment: If $C$ is large, then the category of elements $\int P$ is large, and the correspondence in (12) is only exhibiting $P$ in terms of a _large_ colimit of represntables.

Comment: You said that. But where in the proof of the statement that $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathcal C^\mathrm{op}}$ is the free cocompletion is that a problem? As I explained one needs co-Yoneda only in the uniqueness part, and there one doesn't need to worry about size issues as far as I can see (as I explained above).

Comment: Have you read my messages?

Comment: (12) is completely irrelevant, but (6) is not well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

We define $\widetilde F(P)$, for any presheaf $P$, by the colimit of $\int P\to \mathcal C\to \mathcal D$. Since $\mathcal D$ has only small colimits this is only well-defined for $\int P$ small. Hence we need to assume that $\mathcal C$ is small.